# understanding the error message: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: google is not defined at initMap

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-apps-script

Hello I am very new to Javascript. I am working on a personal project and using the Google API for Javascript maps and markers. I was following example through Google's documentation and for some reason I am getting "Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: google is not defined at initMap" error message on the console. The map and code works fine.

I want to ask what was wrong with my code for this to happen?

here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Trail Locator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" >
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Static Map preview</h1>
    <div id="map"></div>
    
      <script async
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCNyQGZ4tzTaxvFekb0gsksLcqytVms-kM&callback=initMap">
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my Javascript code:

```
// Initialize and add the map
let map;

async function initMap() {

  // The location of Uluru
  const position = { lat: -25.344, lng: 131.031 };
  // Request needed libraries.
  //@ts-ignore
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
  const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");

  getLocation();
  // The map, centered at Uluru
  map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: position,
    mapId: "b003ec40387a4e50",
  });

  // The marker, positioned at Uluru
  const marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
    map: map,
    position: position,
    title: "Uluru",
  });
}

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lng = position.coords.longitude;
  var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
  map.setCenter(pos);
  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos,
    map: map,
    title: "current position"
  })
}

initMap();
```

I may be not too familiar with JavaScript or Asynchronous functions. I had done some research and, correct me if I am wrong, ReferenceError happens when library was not initialized before a function was called.

In my case, the google library should be initialized first for this function to work through the google API. I have included this in my HTML as:

`<script async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCNyQGZ4tzTaxvFekb0gsksLcqytVms-kM&callback=initMap"> </script>`

The error points to the code:
`const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");`

Am i wrong with this?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: You are calling initMap manually (`initMap()`) - instead of letting google maps call it (`&callback=initMap`) once it has finished loading.

Comment: You're sharing your google API key in your code (`key=YOUR_API_KEY`). I advice you to reset the api key so nobody is going to abuse it.

Comment: i was getting the error Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: google is not defined at initMap. also thank you for pointing about the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Maps JavaScript API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview#Inline) states the following.

> When the script is executed, it will call the function specified using the callback parameter.

In your case, the function `initMap` is the callback function. So when the API is loaded, google calls your `initMap` function.

The reason why you're getting the error, is because you're calling the `initMap` function yourself, *before* the maps API is loaded. Removing the last line of your JavaScript code (`initMap()`) will resolve the error.